# How to filter a result returned by a function get_entries() of a stream entries driver in pyrocms?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a stream/table named `profiles`. All of its column are stream-fields. I am trying to restrict the result returned by the the function, get_entries() depending on some criteria. Below is my code:

```
    $data = [
        'stream'    => 'profiles',
        'namespace' => 'users',
        'where'     => 'user_id = 3'     // lets say, this is my criteria
    ];

    $row = $this->streams->entries->get_entries($data); // returns empty
```

The varaible, `$row` resulted in empty array. Although there is one row in table, `profiles` where `user_id` is 3. I have read the documentation of pyrocms and it pretty much says the exact way to use the where clause (just like above).

NOTE: I have also tried writing like

> 'where' => 'profiles.user_id = 3'`

joy !to avoid table conflict. Still no

But when I write the code like this:
$row = $this->streams->entries->get_entries($query);

```
        $query = [
            'stream'    => 'profiles',
            'namespace' => 'users'     
        ];
        // No where clause this time

        $row = $this->streams->entries->get_entries($query);
```

This time $row returns all rows including the row with user id 3.

I am unable to use the where clause in get_entries in a right way. I might have done some mistake. Help me out guyz

NOTE: I am using community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be due to a bug (well, not a bug, but a feature that doesn't work as intended).

If I'm intentionally issue a wrong query, the sql query output is

```
SELECT [ ... ] LEFT JOIN `default_profiles` as `profiles` ON `profiles`.`user_id`=`default_profiles`.`created_by` WHERE (user_id` = 1) ORDER BY `default_profiles`.`created` DESC
```

Here you see that PyroCMS tries to lookup the data for the "created_by" field. And that doesn't work in this case.

If you disable the 'created_by' field, you should get the correct row:

```
$this->streams->entries->get_entries(
  array(
    'stream' => 'profiles',
    'namespace' => 'users',
    'where' => 'user_id = 3',
    'disable' => 'created_by'
  )
);
```

It would be great if you could file an issue on the pyrocms github page. If you won't I'll do it in the next few days.

Comment: yea, it worked. Now I know why 'created_by' was the culprit. When we insert the data in stream without logging into the application. 'created_by' filed could not get the logged in user id, hence mark the NULL. 

Thanks ! you put me in the right direction. Definitely an issue with pyrocms. You can file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public function get_entries($table, $where) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($table);
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $this->db->where($key, $value);
        }
        $this->query = $this->db->get();
        foreach ($this->query->result_array() as $row) {
            $array1[] = $row;
        }
        if ($this->query->num_rows() == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return $array1;
    }
```

call this model function as

```
$row = $this->streams->entries->get_entries('profiles',array('user_id '=>3));
```